# Facebook login suddenly stopped in my facebook integrated android app since this morning

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-authentication

It was working fine till last night and I havent really made any change to my app. I now see a blank white screen with "facebook" written on top after I click on the auth/login button.
Heres what I have tried so far without any positive results.

1. Deleted my debug.keystore->regenerated it and updated the hash on
   FB(just in case it has expired).
2. Changed DEFAULT_AUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE
   in facebook.java(in the FB SDK) to -1.
3. Upgraded to the latest FB
   SDK.(From 3.15 to 3.19)

FYI: I am seeing this issue with an app I am currently developing.
Would really appreciate any help.

Auth fragment:

```
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sarthi_auth, container,
            false);
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view
            .findViewById(R.id.loginButton);



    if (Session.getActiveSession().isOpened() == false) {
        authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays
                .asList(extended_read_permissions));
        authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(user_data_permissions));
        PackageInfo info;
        try {
            info = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "com.you.name", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md;
                md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
                // String something = new
                // String(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
                Log.e("hash key", something);
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
            Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("exception", e.toString());
        }
    }

    return view;
```

Comment: Jai can you post your code of activity/fragment in which you are using Facebook?

Comment: Pasted the login code. The result of this is handled in the fb session state call back handler I implement.

Comment: The issue is back and nothing seems to help- I am guessing there is some issue at the backend at FB? Anyone else experiencing this too? Special thanks to the genius who downvoted the question and my temporary fix :)

Answer (score -1):

Restarting eclipse seemed to have magically fixed the issue(no amount of clean->rebuild helped)
The app now works with 3.15 and 3.19.
With and without DEFAULT_AUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE reset to -1 (/32665)

The only persistent change I have is the updated debug hash.
One of two things then:
1)The hash key had expired( in this case I expect some sort of msg being thrown like key mismatch or something.
2)It was a temporary issue with the FB backend that got fixed( I have seen multiple unresolved instances here where they suspected the same; in which case, not cool FB :/ )